# SlideShow with 5 images one portrait (middle one) and four landscape (2 left and 2 right) to the middle

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I would like to create a `slideshow` using `CSS3` and `HTML5`. 
There will always be a `portrait image` in the middle and 2 landscape images to the left and right respectively  to the `portrait` image (the heights of the two 'landscape images' combined equal the height of the portrait image).
Hence on screen there will be 5 images.
Normally when the use clicks on one image, a pop-up displays the enlarged image.

Could you please provide a solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. These five images, are static? Do they change during the lifecycle of the page?

Comment: Yes they change. When the user clicks on the next set (arrow left or right), a new set of images appears. I want a slideshow effet on the 5 next images.